# ExpressJS: Middleware control flow for Router.param() & Router.use()

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

In my Express.js app, I have some custom validations and parameter parsing. For one of my routes, I'm expecting the obj_id to be provided as part of the route. If mongoose is unable to find an obj with that ID in the DB, then we return a 404 error. Given that I'm putting the router.param call before the router.use call, I'd expect the param validation to execute first. However, with node-inspector, I'm able to verify that the param function is not being reached before the custom middleware.

How do I execute the param parsing before the middleware?

Please note that this middleware is being used on multiple functions, so I don't want to add it into the router call.

```
router.param('obj', function(req, res, next, id){
  Obj.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, obj){
    if (err || !obj) {
      res.status(404).json({error: {message: "No obj with that ID", type: "bad_parameters.unknown_obj"}});
    } else {
      req.obj = obj;
      next();
    }
  });
});

router.use(function(req,res,next){
  ...
  //Do some validations
  ...
  if(error) return res.status(400).json(error);
  next();
});
...
//Other routes that are working well
...
router.get('/:obj', obj);
```

Expected error:

```
404 {error: {message: "No obj with that ID", type: "bad_parameters.unknown_obj"}}
```

Actual error:

```
400 {error: {message: "Validation failed", type: "bad_parameters"}}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `param` handlers are executed when the middleware/route stack execution reaches a route handler that contains placeholders. Did you try moving the middleware as another another argument to `router.get()` *before* your actual route handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using router.use() which attach to the middleware stack and get executed in its declaration order whenever the router is triggered by a request on its defined routes.

If you replace `router.use()` with `router.all()` it'll be executed after the router.param().
So you can do something like:

```
router.route('/:obj')
            .all(validationMiddleware)
            .get(getHandler);
router.param('obj', resolveObj);
```